# How do we run function if previous props change in react native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-props

I get error: undefined is not a object evaluating prevProps.route.params.connectionString

At first prevProps.route.params.connectionString is undefined until it is set from a different function. Trying to figure out the best way to only run this.fetchApiData(connectionString) when the prop has changed.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
   const {connectionString} = this.props.route.params;
    if (prevProps.route.params.connectionString !== connectionString) {
        this.fetchApiData(connectionString);
    }
    
}
```

Comment: What do you get when you `console.log(this.props)` or `console.log(prevProps)`? Is there a chance that the prop you are looking for is called `navigation` instead of `route`?

Comment: At first I get all my props printed to console and the prop that I am looking for is undefined how out if the code runs again it has a value. that's because the first time there is no prop. trying to figure out how to compare even if its undefined

Comment: If `this.props.route` is undefined, you might want to return early from the function.

Comment: Or instead of `const {connectionString} = this.props.route.params` you could do `const connectionString = this.props.route?.params?.connectionString`